# How to add files to same directory in MapReduce job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I have a case that a MapReduce job will be executed a few times daily. What I would like to do is store the results into same output directory.

I'm getting this error:

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory
```

I'm not sure how I could incrementally store into same folder, is there any example that I could look at?

Answer (score 0):

When you store file in hdfs it caused duplication so you have to add timesatmp with file name so fill will be add according to timestamp.

add     filenam_$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%S")

for example ,

when we add file in hdfs using commandLine

```
hadoop dfs -put inputfile /inputfile_$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%S")
```

in hdfs

```
hadoop dfs -ls /

-rw-r--r--   1 kishore supergroup          0 2014-11-06 22:28 /inputfile_2014-11-06-29
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.  The usual reason you'd want to do that is to be able to concatenate the results over time as input into a later map reduce job.  You can achieve that instead by choosing a root directory and writing into a uniquely named child directory each time you run.  For example, write into directory /data/output/d001 the first run, directory /data/output/d02 the second run, etc.  When you want to use all of those directories as input into a single job, set /data/output as your input directory.